# How do you account for server-side redirects in an app shell?

Tags: service-worker, app-shell

I am working on implementing a service worker which caches and serves an app shell to certain routes on my site.

I am running into a problem in that the route can sometimes (based on a query parameter, say) cause a redirect on the server side. However, once the user is being served an app shell, they never actually hit the server again, and the redirects aren't happening.

This seems like a problem inherent to app shells. Looking for thoughts and guidance on handling cases like these.

---

Additional details for clarity:

1. User hits `https://www.example.com`
2. Service worker is installed, subsequently serving an app shell for the `/` route
3. Some time later, the user hits the site again, but their account has been flagged for a security review. Normally, the server would handle this redirection, redirecting the user to, for example, `https://www.example.com/account/security`
4. However, due to the presence of the app shell, the server has no opportunity to perform such a redirect.

Comment: Does getting https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/631 deployed into a production version of Workbox address your use case? We've been planning on cutting a new minor release soon. Or if the problem that you're not sure how to start including the query parameter in your navigation URLs once the App Shell takes over?

Comment: @JeffPosnick right now we're manually doing in sw-precache what the above change will allow us to do in Workbox. But there's still an open question in my mind about how you handle purely server-side redirects, like reading from the server's session storage and redirecting based on something there.

Comment: The answer can't be as cut and dry as "implement the same routing logic on the frontend", can it? If so, it seems like a non-starter for teams like ours that have massive amounts of redirect logic built into their server-side routing.

Comment: In that scenario, it sounds like you'd need to have the client ask the server periodically (perhaps every time there's a History API navigation), via a lightweight `fetch()`, whether there's a reason to go to a special page. And then if the server responds yes, we need to redirect, you can explicitly set `location` to the security checkup URL, which is blacklisted from App Shell navigation.

Answer (score 0):

(Promoting this from the comment section. It's not the only possible approach, but depending on how comfortable you are with running the redirect logic via client-side JavaScript, it should accomplish what you describe.)

In that scenario, it sounds like you'd need to have the client ask the server periodically (perhaps every time there's a History API navigation), via a lightweight fetch(), whether there's a reason to go to a special page. And then if the server responds yes, and you need to redirect, you can explicitly set `location` to the security checkup URL, which should be blacklisted from App Shell navigation.